# No module named “” error when loading the pickle file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I created a model and I saved it in a pickle file using the Algorithm SVR(Support Vector Regression)

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(model,open('carb patients data/Pickles/svr.pickle', 'wb'))
```

In jupyter notebook it gives an error

> can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

So I converted that jupyter file in to a .py file and downloaded it and executed using the Python Idle. Then it got saved in that particular location. But when I try to load my pickle file from another Jupyter Notebook it gives an error called,

> No module named 'sklearn.svm._classes'

The code how i tried to load the pickle file,

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, flash, jsonify
import numpy as np
import pickle as p
import json
from sklearn import ensemble
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/', methods=['POST'])
def makecalc():
  data = request.get_json()
  prediction = np.array2string(model.predict(data))

  return jsonify(prediction)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   modelfile = 'Clustering Patients/carb patients data/Pickles/svr.pickle'
   model = p.load(open(modelfile, 'rb'))
   app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Any thing I have done wrong or is it an issue in the Jupyter Notebook? How can I load my saved pickle file?

Comment: Try to also import `sklearn`, perhaps `sklean.svm` and possibly even `sklearn.svm._classes.` Currently, your code can't find that module, because you didn't import it.

Comment: Yeah did that too..but it gives the same error message :(

Comment: Could you update your code with your amended attempts?

Comment: i have the same issue. I changed the interpreter from conda to python. The issue was fixed.  But i need to run it in the conda environment